# Django: accessing a table via dict-like interface

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I have situation in Django where I have a model called S which can have a series of attributes, but I have no idea currently what attributes will be relevant/required. In order to handle this I am thinking of creating a additional model SAttrib which mimics a dictionary entry and accessing it via a metadata property. See below.

```
class S(models.Model):                                                                                                                                               
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.name)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "stest"
    def _get_metadata(self):
        class AD(dict):
            def __init__(self, id):
                self.id = id
            def __getitem__(self, key):
                return SampleAttrib.objects.filter(sample_id=self.id, attrib_key=key).get().attrib_value

        return AD(self.id)

    metadata = property(_get_metadata)

class SampleAttrib(models.Model):
    s_id = models.ForeignKey("S")
    attrib_key = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    attrib_value = models.TextField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 's_attrib'
        unique_together = (('s_id', 'attrib_key'),)
```

I would like to make it so that I have access the attributes stored in SAttrib via implementing it as a property. So I would be able to access values like so:

```
y = S.objects.get()
y.metadata["foo"]
```

But then it becomes a mess and requires a lot of additional code for setting and saving objects / contains etc.

```
s = S.objects.get()
s.metadata["foo"] = "spam"

.....
```

Is there a better way of structuring this or something thats already in Django that I'm missing?

All suggestions welcome....

Thanks

Comment: If you are using Django 1.8+ and PostgreSQL, have a look at HStoreField, this gives you pretty much what you want to achieve within the same model. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#hstorefield

Comment: I would probably use just a plain text field called `metadata` and use json to serialise/deserialise the stored dict. If you need to run raw queries on the keys/values, this is not ideal because only the latest mysql version has functions for manipulating json. Not sure about other DB engines.

Comment: I'm trying to make this as backend independent as possible - but that definitely solves the problem if I use hstore on postgresql. Same kind of issue for the json.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, however your suggestion appears to only work on specific versions of database backends / not widely portable

Comment: on the contrary, JSON can be stored on any database. What postgresql provides with JSONB is a very fast searchable implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a lot wrong with the idea, except for the fact that you seem to have made it needlessly complicated with the use of the `_get_metadata` function. You may be having a bit of a performance issue becaue of it as well.

This kind of two-table approach is or rather was quite popular in many web apps when you don't know in advance what kind of name/value pairs you will be storing in your table. However the practice is now on the decline thanks to nosql solution and most RDBMS now supporting JSON data types.

Django has built in support for Postgresql's excellent JSONB field. For other databases, tried and tested JSONFields are available so using JSONFields would give you a pretty good database independent solution.